# Broken links for bounties tab in profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page

I found a bug.  There are a few different ways to reproduce:

**By Direct URL**

- Go directly to [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson?tab=bounties&sort=offered).
- Notice the Page Not Found error page.

**By Clicking**

- Go to a user's profile page, such as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson).
- On the Summary tab, go down to the Bounties panel in the far lower-left corner.
- Click any of the sort buttons, such as "offered".
- Click the "view more" link
- Notice it takes you to the URL I mentioned above and you get the error.

**Another Path**

- Go to the bounties tab on a user's profile page, such as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson?tab=badges).
- Click the "offered" sort button.
- Notice it works, and the URL is exactly as the other paths.
- Grab the URL and paste it in a new tab.  See the error.

  - Or on my browser, simple pressing the enter key in the url line will resubmit and error.

None of the other tabs appear to be affected by this bug.

Answer (score 3):

When I click the tabs, I am taken to the same URL as your direct link, and it works. When you click any of the other tabs, the entire page does not get reloaded.

The `sort` parameter is taken incorrectly by the server for the bounties tab; any value for the `sort` parameter (`active`, `offered`, or `earned`) is broken as well.

---

Bottom line:
Only when the page is requested with the parameter do you see an error.

Comment: You are taken to the same URL, but not the same URI. Or maybe that's backwards?

Comment: @ColeJohnson The JavaScript is adding the `sort` parameter to the URL, but the server is not recognizing the parameter. The problem is server-side.